# How I can to define a axiom in Z3py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I have to do a axioms in Z3, but I watched the example of https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm (Modeling with Quantifiers) and I don't understand the majority of things. I would like if someone could give me a example of little axiom in Z3py, for help me to understand.

The example that I execute is it:

```
Type     = DeclareSort('Type')
subtype  = Function('subtype', Type, Type, BoolSort())
array_of = Function('array_of', Type, Type)
root     = Const('root', Type)

x, y, z  = Consts('x y z', Type)

axioms = [ ForAll(x, subtype(x, x)),
           ForAll([x, y, z], Implies(And(subtype(x, y), subtype(y, z)),
                                     subtype(x, z))),
           ForAll([x, y], Implies(And(subtype(x, y), subtype(y, x)),
                                  x == y)),
           ForAll([x, y, z], Implies(And(subtype(x, y), subtype(x, z)),
                                     Or(subtype(y, z), subtype(z, y)))),
           ForAll([x, y], Implies(subtype(x, y),
                                  subtype(array_of(x), array_of(y)))),

           ForAll(x, subtype(root, x))
           ]
s = Solver()
s.add(axioms)
print s
print s.check()
print "Interpretation for Type:"
print s.model()[Type]
print "Model:"
print s.model()
```

The problem is that I don't understand the output.

```
[root = Type!val!0,
 subtype = [else ->
            Or(And(If(Var(0) == Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!0) ==
                   Type!val!1,
                   If(Var(1) == Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!0) ==
                   Type!val!1),
               And(If(Var(0) == Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!0) ==
                   Type!val!0,
                   If(Var(1) == Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!0) ==
                   Type!val!1),
               And(If(Var(0) == Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!0) ==
                   Type!val!0,
                   If(Var(1) == Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!1,
                      Type!val!0) ==
                   Type!val!0))],
 array_of = [else -> Type!val!1]]
```

For this reason is that I need to check a little example for understand better how works it

Comment: The output simply says `root` can be any type (here given the name `Type!val!0`, and `subtype` is a function that matches every input to the large expression, and `array_of` is a function that matches everything to `Type!val!1`, which is different than `root`. That's the meaning of the `else ->` notation; if it was mapping fixed inputs to other values, they'd havre been listed. And you can just read the expression as is: It's a disjunction (`Or`) of a bunch of conjunctions (`And`), each of which itself is a conditional (`If`). Hope that's clear!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referring to this piece of code:

```py
Type     = DeclareSort('Type')
subtype  = Function('subtype', Type, Type, BoolSort())
array_of = Function('array_of', Type, Type)
root     = Const('root', Type)

x, y, z  = Consts('x y z', Type)

axioms = [ ForAll(x, subtype(x, x)),
           ForAll([x, y, z], Implies(And(subtype(x, y), subtype(y, z)),
                                     subtype(x, z))),
           ForAll([x, y], Implies(And(subtype(x, y), subtype(y, x)),
                                  x == y)),
           ForAll([x, y, z], Implies(And(subtype(x, y), subtype(x, z)),
                                     Or(subtype(y, z), subtype(z, y)))),
           ForAll([x, y], Implies(subtype(x, y),
                                  subtype(array_of(x), array_of(y)))),

           ForAll(x, subtype(root, x))
           ]
s = Solver()
s.add(axioms)
print s
print s.check()
print "Interpretation for Type:"
print s.model()[Type]
print "Model:"
print s.model()
```

An axiom is nothing but a quantified assertion (see how the list `axioms` are added to the solver using `s.add`), and they are typically about uninterpreted functions. (In this case, `subtype` and array_of`).

Not quite sure what you're struggling with. Please ask a specific question. Did you try running this code? Did it produce what you expected?

Comment: I edited the first comment, I want to understand how works it, and how could work a little example because I don't have any idea